# Perl CGI.pm encoding - wrong encoding for "ě"

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8, cgi

I have a simple web page that uses CGI.pm This is what I do:

1. when I call any perl CGI.pm function and use czech character "ě" for value of a textfield, label of radio_group or anything else I get �› insetad of "ě"
2. this is extremly weird - since the whole page is utf8 (<meta name="charset" content="utf-8"/> ). Especially since this works

   ```
     print '<textfield value="ěěěě" >';
   ```
3. therefore I am positive - it has to be CGI.pm causing the problem... I tried to put

   ```
     use utf8;
     utf8::decode($textfield_value);
   ```

   at the beginning of my scirpt and it fixed the CGI.pm problem but made all other characters in the script (those that are regulary printed) look funny..

Any ideas???

Comment: Crosspost http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=949883

Answer (score 1):

Set the `accept-charset` attribute in your form fields to `UTF-8`?

```
<form action="/..." accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

This might not be sufficient to solve your problem, but it is often necessary to force the client browser to utf8-encode the form data that gets sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing the ě's with their octal or hex escapes? Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an HTML code for the character.

Comment: Finding the codepoint: `perl -CA -E'say sprintf "%04X", ord shift' ě`. The -CA flag tells perl [that `@ARGV` is UTF-8](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-C-%5b_number%2flist_%5d*). So it would be `&#x011B;` as an HTML entity.